# For a given Date object, capture it's value relevant to GMT timezone

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime, sql-timestamp

In my application running on Java 8, I have a Date object. The timezone for this object depends on the client's location.

At one particular point, I need to convert this Date to GMT so that it could be comparable to a value that I access from the DB.

I tried SimpleDateFormat and ZonedDateTime, but there's a pain-point. These API's provide me GMT time in String values, which is perfectly fine. However, once I parse it and assign it to a Date object, it is back to my local timezone!

For Ex:

```
public class TimeZoneDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date istDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        ZonedDateTime gmtTime = istDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
        System.out.println(gmtTime);

        Date gmtDate = Date.from(gmtTime.toInstant());
        System.out.println(gmtDate);
    }
}
```

In the code above, ***gmtTime*** displays the right value relevant to the GMT timezone, but ***gmtDate*** (the Date object) prints value in the local time zone.

***P.S.: My ultimate goal is to have a the GMT value in a java.sql.TimeStamp object.***

How could this be achieved?

**UPDATE 1:**
After going through the comments & replies I understand that the Date object just holds a long value containing milliseconds.
**BUT,** my expectation here is that when this line is executed:

```
Date gmtDate = Date.from(gmtTime.toInstant());
```

Whatever time the object ***gmtTime*** contains, I need to capture just that time in a TimeStamp or Date object. The motive is to then be able to make comparison with a value persisted in the database. I'm passing the date as parameter to my SQL query.

Can someone pls help me understand how can this be achieved?

Comment: "However, once I parse it and assign it to a Date object, it is back to my local timezone!" Not really. Date objects aren't "in" any time zone. They just represent instants of time. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: Always, and even more so when using Java 8 (or later), avoid the `Date` and `Timestamp` classes. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *comparison with a value persisted in the database* — as in is equal or is before or after? Would you prefer to compare in SQL or in Java? I’m sure we can help.

Comment: No need to ever use `java.sql.TimeStamp` again. Replaced by [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) in JDBC 4.2 and later. `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;` and `OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;`. Likewise, never use `java.util.Date` nor `java.util.Calendar` ever again. Supplanted by *java.time* when JSR 310 was adopted years ago.

Comment: @OleV.V.: I'm passing the date as parameter to my SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

The answer is in @BasilBourque’s comment: use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
    PreparedStatement yourPreparedStatement = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "select smth from your_table where your_time_stamp_col < ?;");
    OffsetDateTime gmtTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(1, gmtTime);
```

This requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant JDBC driver, I think that about all of us are using that by now. Which is good because it allows us to bypass `java.sql.Timestamp` and the other date-time types in `java.sql`. They are all poorly designed and long outdated.

As others have said, neither of the outdated classes `Date` and `Timestamp` have any time zone or offset from UTC/GMT.

### Some related questions

- [Get GMT Time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236052/get-gmt-time-in-java)
- [SimpleDateFormat returns wrong time zone during parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107898/simpledateformat-returns-wrong-time-zone-during-parse)
- [Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773390/getting-the-date-from-a-resultset-for-use-with-java-time-classes)

Comment: This is likely only to work if a) your driver supports `OffsetDateTime` and b) you use the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Thank you, you are correct. A JDBC 4.2 compliant driver *does* support `OffsetDateTime` by definition. The database datatype ought to be `timestamp with time zone`. If it’s a mere `timestamp`(without time zone), one needs to use  `LocalDateTime` on the Java side instead. Everything else is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `Date` class is part of the old outdated (no pun intended) infrastructure. If it is at all possible get rid of it and just use `java.time` package. But if you must work with `Date` then your problem with time zone is not a problem. your line `System.out.println(gmtDate);` only prints it with your local time zone, since the system assumes that it is the best option. But regardless of that `Date` holds a particular moment in time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. Class `Date` has methods [compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-), [after()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) and [before()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-) that allow you to compare 2 Dates. Also `Date` has method [getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) that returns you the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this date. So you can compare the `long` values. But again, The best option is to switch to `java.time` package and classes [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) (and others) have methods compareTo(), isAfter() and isBefore().

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you pls refer to the updated title and 'Update 1' in the question above and help me with some pointers to accomplish it?

Comment: I just let the office and won't be able too answer for tonight.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the semantics of date time classes. `java.util.Date` is a specific point in time, an instant, it has no time zone associated with it. However if you have a time zone you can ask the time zone for the time of that `java.util.Date`.

`java.sql.TimeStamp` is the equivalent of `java.time.LocalDateTime`. It is not an instant and has no time zone associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you pls refer to the updated title and 'Update 1' in the question above and help me with some pointers to accomplish it?

Comment: **Incorrect on `Date`**. The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC defined as a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z where the `Z` means UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). Without the context of UTC or some such reference, you cannot represent a moment.

Comment: **Incorrect on [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html).** That class is actually a subclass of `java.util.Date`, awkwardly adding on a fractional second in nanoseconds while still carrying the milliseconds of `Date`. As `Timestamp` *is* a `Date`, it too represents a moment in UTC. It is most certainly ***not*** equivalent to `LocalDateTime`, which purposely lacks the concepts of time zone or offset-from-UTC. See: [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` was replaced by [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) in JDBC 4.2 and later (not `LocalDateTime` as stated incorrectly on this Answer). See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808424/for-a-given-date-object-capture-its-value-relevant-to-gmt-timezone#comment102055294_57808424) on Question for example code.

Comment: @BasilBourque not really no, `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass but not to a subtype, therefore not a `java.util.Date`. `java.sql.Timestamp`, unlike java.util.Date is in JVM time zone. You can check it out for yourself, the value of Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-06 17:47:11").getTime() depends on the JVM time zone. Also note the `java.time.LocalDateTime` conversion methods on `java.sql.Timestamp` as they are equivalent.

Comment: That two such knowledgeable people can disagree about what a `java.sql.Timestamp` is at all, should send a clear message: **Stay far away from that poorly designed class.**

Comment: @BasilBourque as for java.util.Date and time zone UTC, I defer to John Skeet https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/