# Getting timeStamp in the UTC timezone but I want it in CST

Tags: java, time, timezone-offset

```
Timestamp revsnTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I'm getting revision time in UTC but I want it in CST. How do I convert it?

Comment: What specific `Timestamp` class are you using?  Does it even represent timezones?

Comment: If that is `java.sql.Timestamp`, I recommend you don’t use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. If for an SQL database, use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for a `timestamp with time zone` (recommended for timestamp). Or if for a `timestamp` without time zone use `LocalDateTime` in Java.

Comment: Also as @LouisWassermann hinted, a `java.sql.Timestamp` does not, cannot have a time zone. Does this answer your question? [For a given Date object, capture it's value relevant to GMT timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808424/for-a-given-date-object-capture-its-value-relevant-to-gmt-timezone)

Comment: To get the current time in Cuba Standard Time (CST): `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Havana"))`.