# Convert LocalDateTime to Date with 0 offset

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a LocalDateTime to a Date object with a 0 offset.

The current code I'm using converts LocalDateTime to Date is:
`Date.from(localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))`

LocalDateTime:
`2016-12-07T16:29:12.218`

After being converted to Date:
`2016-12-07T10:29:12.218-0600`

Yes, I see there is a zone offset being passed into toInstant but i'm not sure how to do what i'm asking for.

UPDATE:
I just received more information on my problem saying to set the date with precision and a zone of UTC to make the offset 0.

Comment: An old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object does not know anything about timezones - it does not remember what timezone it's in, and if you print it (by implicitly or explicitly calling `toString()` on it) it will always use the default timezone of the machine it's running on. You cannot have a `Date` object that's in a certain timezone, because `Date` simply does not have to capacity to remember that. Set the timezone on a `SimpleDateFormat` and format the `Date` using that to get it to display in a timezone of choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat returns wrong time zone during parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107898/simpledateformat-returns-wrong-time-zone-during-parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to convert LocalDateTime to Date at your system zone. So, try this instead

```
Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
```